# Can I add junction boxes to reroute these cables?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

I am redoing my cabinets. I had a soffit when when I opened it up to remove I have 3-4 cables running through it. My question is if I do not have enough slack to get it over the joists or I can’t notch the hoist and add a nail plate. Can I cut the line and add two junction boxes to lengthen the romex line? Would this be up to code? I would have it accessible above the cabinets?

Answer (score 4):

**All** junction boxes need to be accessible.

Period.

Don't mess with that rule, it's a very important one.

If the junction boxes meet or exceed the size required for "box fill" (there are calculators on the web, if the one you stumble on at first is not to your liking, choose another, many work fine/easily, or you can read the tables and do the calcs by hand if you like) and are accessible, extending cables that way is code compliant.

*Obligatory opinionated advice to use steel boxes rather than the blue plastic junque.*

Comment: Ok great thank you. I figured I could I just wanted be sure. My thought was to cut the romex and extend it through the two junction boxes while adding a section of romex through. I’m hoping I can just move and lift the cables but I needed a plan b. I figured I could do this as all what I read about code just said romex that is spliced has to be in a junction box.

Comment: @MarcMontano It's in a different section of the code.  The part about splicing the wire says it has to be in a JB.  The part about junction boxes is in a different part and says they must be accessible.

Comment: Ok that’s what I thought when I spice to extend do I need to ground to the junction box with a ground screw or am I able to just connect the grounds with wire nuts since they will not be running into a device they will only be running the current

Comment: Ground the boxes.